# More Efficient Way To Write MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

My site has suddenly started spitting out the following error:

> "Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_645a_1.MYI'; try to repair it"

I remove it, the site works fine.

My server tech support guys suggest I clean up the query and make it more efficient.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT *, FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i') as posttime 
FROM communityposts, communitytopics, communityusers 
WHERE communityposts.poster_id=communityusers.user_id 
AND communityposts.topic_id=communitytopics.topic_id 
ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Perhaps can be done with a JOIN?

Many thanks,

Scott

UPDATE: Here's the working query, I still feel it could be optimised though.

```
SELECT
    communityposts.post_id, communityposts.topic_id, communityposts.post_time,
    communityusers.user_id, , communitytopics.topic_title, communityusers.username,
    communityusers.user_avatar, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i') as post time 
FROM
    communityposts,
    communitytopics,
    communityusers
WHERE 
    communityposts.poster_id=communityusers.user_id
    AND communityposts.topic_id=communitytopics.topic_id
ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: run myisamcheck on the database, it might be corrupted or you are runnig a rather old version of mysql

Comment: use `JOIN`s instead of cross joining with `WHERE` statements.

Comment: Is the key posttime (line 1) supposed to be the same key as post_time (line 5)?

Comment: Is that a temporary table that has the corrupt index?  It seems likely from the location/filename.  Is it possible to get whatever it is that created it to disconnect/reconnect and recreate it for whatever purpose it needs it?

Comment: do queries: REPAIR TABLE communityposts; REPAIR TABLE communitytopics; REPAIR TABLE communityusers;

Comment: OK Im going to give the JOIN a go in the reply posted down the page.

Comment: So I used the query by sehe, and I can confirm I no longer get the error, but it's not returning the correct data as can be seen here: http://www.trancetribe.com in the sidebar

Comment: Dang. I didn't realize people would simply hack directly on a `production` (_live_) site. Wow! @ScottRichardson try the original query again now that it has been repaired?

Comment: Sadly, the error is on the LIVE site. The site has been working FINE for many months. Then all of a sudden it started giving this error. Restoring backups didn't fix the problem :( Using my original query also still doesn't work, even though I repaired, and added indexes as suggested by Rolando.

Comment: FIXED IT! I simply added ONLY the cols that I need, rather than SELECT *, and now it's working!

Comment: Though I still feel that it's not the most efficient code.

Comment: @ScottRichardson: consider upvoting the answers that were most helpful in your eyes

Comment: @sehe, I will as soon as my darn reputation hits 15 :( Sorry!!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    A.*,B.*,C.*,FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i') as posttime  
FROM
    (
        SELECT id,poster_id,topic_id
        FROM communityposts
        ORDER BY post_time DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) cpk
    INNER JOIN communityposts A USING (id)
    INNER JOIN communityusers B ON cpk.poster_id=B.user_id
    INNER JOIN communitytopics C USING (topic_id);
```

If a community post does not have to have a user and a topic, then use LEFT JOINs for the last two joins.

You will need to create a supporting index for the cpk subquqery:

```
ALTER TABLE communityposts ADD INDEX (posttime,id,poster_id,topic_id);
```

This query *has to be the fastest* because the cpk subquery only gets five keys ALL THE TIME.

**UPDATE 2011-10-10 16:28 EDT**

This query eliminiates the ambiguous topic_id issue:

```
SELECT
    A.post_id, cpk.topic_id, A.post_time,
    B.user_id, C.topic_title, B.username,
    B.user_avatar, 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i') as posttime  
FROM
    (
        SELECT id,poster_id,topic_id
        FROM communityposts
        ORDER BY post_time DESC
        LIMIT 5
    ) cpk
    INNER JOIN communityposts A USING (id)
    INNER JOIN communityusers B ON cpk.poster_id=B.user_id
    INNER JOIN communitytopics C ON cpk.topic_id=C.topic_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Rolando. I note that id needs to be changed to post_id. I tried this query however I got: _Column 'topic_id' in from clause is ambiguous_

Comment: I updated my answer with a query that should eliminate the ambiguous topic_id issue

Answer (score 0):

- You could reduce the number of fields selected.

  > The * operator will select all fields from all (3) tables. This may get big. That said,
  >   I think mysql is smart enough to lay this plan out so that it doesn't need to access the data pages **except** for the 5 rows being selected.
- Are you sure that all the involved (foreign) keys are indexed?

Here's my stab:

```
SELECT posts.*, FROM_UNIXTIME(post_time, '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i') as posttime 
FROM communityposts posts
     INNER JOIN communitytopics topics ON posts.topic_id = topics.topic_id
     INNER JOIN communityusers users ON posts.poster_id = users.user_id
ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks sehe, going to give this a go now! Will report back.

Comment: Had to edit line 4.. should be posts.poster_id = users.**user**_id

Comment: Sadly it's not working - I'm no longer getting the original error, however Im also no longer getting any actual results from my activity feed: http://www.trancetribe.com (sidebar)

Comment: @ScottRichardson: I'm sure you know how to revert `posts.*` to `just *`? Of course you'll need to include the fields you use. I was just giving an example to show the gist of what I'd explained.

Comment: Whoops. When changing it back to just *, I get the same original MySQL error again.

Comment: Too bad! Now, I don't know enough to see why `Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_645a_1.MYI'; try to repair it` should go away without repairing it first - but hey, you can try of course. Anyways, is there another database you can test with so that you can at least compare queries? No use testing a dead horse...

Answer (score 0):

Then temp table used for sorting the data probably gets too big. I have seen this happen when the /tmp/ runs out of space. The LIMIT clause does not make it any quicker or easier, as the sorting of the full data set has to be done first.

Under some conditions, MySQL does not use a temp table to sort data. You can read about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

If you manage to meet the right conditions (mostly use the correct indexes), it will also peed up your query.

If this doesn't help (in some cases you can't escape the heavy sorting), try to find out how much free space there is on /tmp/, and see if it can be expanded. Also, as sehe mentioned, selecting only the needed columns (instead of *) can make the temp table smaller and is considered best practice anyway (and so is using explicit JOINs instead of implicit ones).

Comment: Im gonna try the Query below, failing that, I'll try it with just the cols that I need rather than SELECT *.

Comment: Galz, OK I fixed it. I just selected ONLY the cols that I needed, and now the query is working again.